# Web API controller receiving variable nested object

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asynchronous

I am building a Web API controller that will receive variable number of nested json data

for some calls to my controller:

one call can call with 3 four accounts fees

```
{

"studentid":123,

"studentname":"sam",

"totalfee1amnt":20,
"accounts":[ 

    {   "feeid":"xx",
        "fee1amnt":5
    },

    {   "feeid":"xx",
        "fee1amnt":5
    },

    {   "feeid":"xx",
        "fee1amnt":5
    }
    ]
 }
```

//another call can call with 4 four accounts fees

```
{
"studentid":123,
"studentname":"sam",
"totalfee1amnt":25,

"accounts":[ 

    {   "feeid":"xx",
        "fee1amnt":5
    },

    {   "feeid":"xx",
        "fee1amnt":5
    },

    {   "feeid":"xx",
        "fee1amnt":5
    },

    {   "feeid":"xx",
        "fee1amnt":5
    },
    ]
}
```

This controller needs to be dynamic and more data at some calls.

and I need to write this data to a database either with entity framework or just with the normal insert into DB, but I will prefer EF that is Asycn,  and with the "totalfee1amnt" I need to call other SP with this value.

I need to make this code async so multiple call s can happens at the same  time.

I am implementing this using C#

How can I effeciently implement

I am just writing this on a text file to check if all is good.

Below is what I have and I have made some modifications

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/CreditlifeCalc")]
    public string TestJsonInput([FromBody] CreditlifeData input)
    {
        var jsonall = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input.data );
        var clietid = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input.ClientID);

        string path;

        path = (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\\response.json"); 
        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(path))
        {
            // writing data in string
            string dataasstring = jsonall.ToString(); 
            byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes(dataasstring);
            fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);

            // writing data in bytes already
            byte[] data = new byte[] { 0x0 };
            fs.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        return jsonall;
    }

    public class CreditlifeData
    {
        public List<Crreditlife> data { get; set; }
        public string ClientID { get; set; }
    }

    public class Crreditlife
    {
        public int Creditlf_Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Amount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This works fine when calling the API, I need to make sure the clietid  is used as main tag for inserting to Sql server and I need to use EF async for this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why doesn't it meet your expectations?

Comment: It is still unclear what your question is - are you looking for someone to write the whole database insert part for you (unlikely to happen - we dont know what your database looks like in any case)